# Eclipse IWorkbenchPreferencePage warning do not disappear

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, message, jface

I am writing my own `IWorkbenchPreferencePage` in which I create a warning message, such like

```java
setMessage("Not valid string", IMessageProvider.WARNING);
```

But when I set this message the warning is shown, but how can I ensure that the message disappears when it is valid again?

Answer (score 0):

You call `setMessage` again with a null message:

```java
setMessage(null, IMessageProvider.NONE);
```

You will have to arrange to keep validating everything as values change.